# Как подключить рекламу к Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, реклама, ads

Я хочу подключить к программе рекламу, но видеоролик по которому я учусь это делать довольно старый, потому Android studio поменялся
Где я теперь могу найти эту вкладку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нету в студии таких вкладок больше (хотя я и не искал, может где-то и есть).

Всё добавляется ручками в пару секунд.

В `build.gradle` добавьте в `dependences` зависимость:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
```

В манифест добавьте AdMob App ID:

```
<application>
    <!-- Пример AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
</application>
```

В активности инициализируйте адмоб:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
    }
});
```

Готово! Реклама подключена к проекту.

Далее можете использовать и вставлять [баннеры](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) и [межстраничные](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) объявления в нужных вам местах.

Самый простой вариант вставки баннера, прямо в разметку:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/adView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  ads:adSize="BANNER"
  ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
```

А далее загрузите рекламу в этот баннер:

```
AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

И ура - вы показали свою первую рекламу в приложении ))

Comment: У меня в первом же пункте провал, не могу найти build.grandle а когда ввожу в поиск dependences, ничего не выдает

Comment: Не можете найти build.gradle? Этот файл находится в корне проекта android.

Comment: Нашел, спасибо.

Comment: У меня не получилось, при запуске вылетает