# Как реализовать рекламу admob при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, google-adsense

столкнулся с проблемой интеграции рекламы в моё приложение.
"Здравствуйте,нужна помощь в реализации такой функции в Andorid проект.
Я сделал авторизацию через FireBase. Теперь нужно что бы по кнопке показывалась реклама и после просмотра засчитывались поинты,если же человек сидит без интернета и реклама не показывалась,то поинты не засчитывались.Смотря сколько реклам просмотрел,соответственно,что бы для каждого юзера было своё количество. Вот я не знаю как это реализовать. Может кто помочь?"
Посмотрел один видео-урок как встроить рекламу сделал класс как в видео уроке,но не совсем понятно зачем там нужна 1 строка (отметил на скриншоте),так же не уверен всё ли правильно я сделал в этом классе.
 - https://prnt.sc/ragjp5

Comment: setContentView(); устанавливает layout (xml) файл из ресурсов в качестви макета для данной activity

Comment: Хорошо я про  этот класс пока что забил,нашёл тут на форуме статью https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086908/Как-подключить-рекламу-к-android-studio/1086918#1086918 , в ней написано в активности это как? я хочу что бы было при нажатии на кнопку с id - clickreclam появлялась реклама , в Onclicklistener оно не хочет писать,как это реализовать?

Comment: вы рановато задумались над интеграцией рекламы, сперва необходимо разобраться с азами

Comment: Я понимаю,но я решил просто создать простенькое приложение с выводом рекламы и не совсем понимаю как это реализовать. Извиняюсь,что задаю такие глупые вопросы. Можете помочь?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Обработчик кнопки, которая включает рекламу
    adButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showAd();
        }
    });

    //Вызывайте, чтобы показать рекламу
    private void showAd() {
         if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
              mInterstitialAd.show();
         } else {
              Log.d("TAG", "Реклама недоступна");
         }
     }

    private void loadAd() {
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
```

Чтобы получить вознаграждение:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
//Когда реклама закончилась, даём бонус и подгружаем новую рекламу
            onRewarded()
            loadAd()
    }
});
```